# pytset - how to configure to show logging messages

Tags: logging, pytest

Previously asked about the pytest logging in [Where is “--log-level command-line options” explained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465528) and still not clear how it works and how to configure. Please help understand what I am doing wrong.

**test.py**

```
import logging


def test_log_message(caplog):
    logger = logging.getLogger("test_log_message")

    caplog.set_level(logging.DEBUG, logger="test_log_message")
    logger.debug("foobar")
```

Expected "foobar" will be displayed by executing the pytest but it does not show "foobar".

```
$ pytest --log-level=DEBUG test.py -k test_log_message
=============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.8, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ****
plugins: forked-1.3.0, pytest_check-1.0.1, xdist-2.2.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                  

test.py .                                                                                                                                                                                                   [100%]

================================================================================================ 1 passed in 0.16s ================================================================================================
```

## Versions

```
$ pytest --version
pytest 6.2.2

$ python --version
Python 3.8.8
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#confval-log_cli):

“By setting the log_cli configuration option to true, pytest will output logging records as they are emitted directly into the console.”

Try adding the following to your `pytest.ini`

```
[pytest]
log_cli=True
```

You could also pass it as a parameter to the pytest command:

```
pytest -o log_cli=True
```

If the log level inside the tests needs to be different than in other places then you could use the caplog fixture. From the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html): “Inside tests it is possible to change the log level for the captured log messages. This is supported by the caplog fixture:”

```
def test_foo(caplog):
    caplog.set_level(logging.INFO)
    logging.info(“yo”)
```

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid --log-level would be different from live logging with log_cli, which has its own -o log_cli_level which would be different from --log-level, which is log_level in pytest.ini.

Comment: I updated the answer. Maybe log_cli option and caplog fixture is what you are looking for